# Android AlarmManager execution time problem

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have set a AlarmManager which will give alarm repeatedly after certain time. I used following code for that.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewDoughnut.this, NotificationMessage.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ViewDoughnut.this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,nextAlarmTime, alarmInterval, sender);
```

Now to execute proper work at the alarm time I have created the following class extending  BroadcastReceiver. Now I need the time in millisecond when the Alarm work should execute in that class. How to get it?

```
public class NotificationMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // Display an alert that we've received a message.
    // @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // here I need the time when the alarm should execute.
    }
}
```

Here I like to add, system time is not working for me, because if the device is switch off at the alarm time, it execute that when the device is on after that time. But I need the time when it should execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that derives from Application which holds all global variables. Then just set a long variable to hold the time before initialising the alarm

Comment: It will be not effective for my case because it is a repeating alarm and multiple alarms are effective at same time for different event.